# C# Windows Explorer File Preview

Tags: c#, .net, file, preview, explorer

How can I use the file preview of the explorer for files or generate a preview with a library?

I have tried the Windows Codepack API, but when trying to get the preview for all kind of office docs, I only get the Icon of the office doc, although the windows explorer shows the preview of the file correctly (windows 10)

Heres my code:

```
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(absolutePath);
            shellFile.Thumbnail.FormatOption = ShellThumbnailFormatOption.ThumbnailOnly;
            Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
            shellThumb.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Corresponding to this post I tried to fix the issue, but the approaches that were shown there didnt work [Windows API Code Pack - ShellFile not generating PDF bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262342/windows-api-code-pack-shellfile-not-generating-pdf-bitmap)

Comment: Thumbnail != Preview. Which one do you need?

Comment: I need the preview

Comment: Then have a look at [How to get the IPreviewHandler for a file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633246/how-to-get-the-ipreviewhandler-for-a-file-extension).

Comment: Okay, know I installed the nuget package ShellShark, but what do I need to execute the code of the Methode ``GetShellClsidForFileType``? Furthermore, I am working in an asp net core application in combination class library, therefore I dont have an UI, and I want to keep this situation, unless there is no other way arround it, to get the preview...